# Interest in How to build a water feature?

Tags: discussion

We have one question about water features but I will grant that it is a specialized aspect of gardening.
If there is interest I can write up a series of posts that discuss:

- choice of materials
- how to install
- maintenance and over wintering
- what plants do well and what plants do too well in damp or wet environments
- how having a pond will help control pests in your garden

This time I will put it up as a Google doc with a link here so if anyone wants to do editing or add content they can.  Then a once-a-day post should cover any SE rules.

So, is water gardening too specialized or is it a good fit here?

Comment: I'm surprised there has been no feedback yet on this...  I guess we don't have that many pond/water feature questions or users that have them at home, but you shouldn't let that discourage you from writing. I'd certainly like to see some diversity in the landscaping questions and give that term in the site's name some meaning. Maybe you can wait a bit, so that we can learn a bit more from the first mini-series that you had. I know you had a meta post on that (which again hasn't gotten responses), but I do hope to get to that soon...

Comment: Sure enough, there's much to do in the garden right now anyway.